# Mounting external component of split AC on hollow brick wall

Tags: walls, air-conditioning, mini-split

I have a small split system (Philco Phs25ha4cpi). The external component weighs 25kg, and I have mounting brackets like these:

[image: two simple mounting brackets]

And a wall made from bricks like these:

[image: hollow brick]

My question is what kinds of screws, and what quantity should I use to mount the bracket? I usually use [these](https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-903779468-tarugo-espyga-n-12-x-100-unidades-ladrillo-hueco-y-comun-py-_JM#position=1&search_layout=stack&type=item&tracking_id=4ada8e13-9fa4-458d-8c39-1f8b0e2136c2) plugs for dry walls (article linked only to show reference photos, not for the text).

I CANNOT go through the wall, the other side is not mine.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I securely hang a very heavy object on wall made of hollow bricks?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/164514/how-can-i-securely-hang-a-very-heavy-object-on-wall-made-of-hollow-bricks) Also, be careful how you drill those bricks, hammer/SDS is likely to shatter them.

Comment: "Does this answer your question?" No, the hollow wall anchors don't work unless I don't use the brackets I already have and I know the plugs exist, I linked one, but I don't know how many to use and what screws to use.

Comment: @Tetsujin "I wouldn't use solid wall plugs in hollow bricks." Those are not solid wall plugs, look [here](https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_NQ_NP_921164-MLA46967947310_082021-O.webp), it expands. "That's why the linked question suggests anchoring them right the way through, not just on the first layer." The other side of that wall is the neighbor's, I cannot go through.

Comment: @Tetsujin In Argentina they are sold specifically for hollow walls, its one of the photos in the MercadoLibre posting, showing how it works for a hollow wall. I have used them before and they hold quite well, and they fail only when the wall fails (catastrophically).

Comment: I can't read any of it, so I've no clue what I'm supposed to be looking for. Anyway, I'm done.

Comment: VTRO because plastic should not be involved. Neither your 'drywall' anchors, nor their fake toggle bolts. - How about *real* toggle bolts? - Also, I don't like your un-braced brackets, but if they came with the thing so be it.

Comment: "I don't know how many to use and what screws to use." - all four holes on each bracket, and the screws that came with the sleeves. Don't put random screws into random sleeves.

Comment: *real* toggle bolts : 1/4 in. x 4 in. Zinc-Plated Toggle Bolt with Round-Head ...
https://www.homedepot.com/p/1-4-in-x-4-in-Zinc-Plated-Toggle-Bolt-with-Round-Head-Phillips-Drive-Screw-10-Piece-803942/204273384 ... Hollow Wall Anchors "Ideal for use in hollow walls and hollow masonry applications"

Comment: @Mazura I get an access denied for that page, but thanks for the name of the bolt, I will search it. So four should be enough to sustain the 25kg, more of which is to one side?

Comment: [Toggle bolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toggle_bolt). 50 pounds? *one* 1/4" toggle bolt is probably good for that or more. But a safety factor of 4 is ideal anyway. And probably at least one of them isn't going to work right because of the location hitting the meat of the brick instead of a hollow spot, so that's why you got the other three... times two (both sides) just because.

Comment: @Mazura Thanks! I will try to find those at my local hardware store. You should probably post that as an answer. :)